# Display singular and plural headers on appropriate context

Tags: django

I'd like to display the plural accordingly in template

```
{% if page.paginator.count <= 1 %}
    <h3 style="display: inline">{{ page.paginator.count }} Comment</h3>
{% else %}
    <h3 style="display: inline">{{ page.paginator.count }} Comments</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Since it's a everyday task,I wonder if it could be achieved in a straightforward way such as template-filer?

Answer (score 3):

Django provides such a function for that. Its name is [`pluralize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize)

Returns a plural suffix if the value is not 1. By default, this suffix is `s`.

```
<h3 style="display: inline"> Comment{{page.paginator.count|pluralize}}</h3>
```

For words that don’t pluralize by simple suffix, you can specify both a singular and plural suffix, separated by a comma.

```
countr{{ total|pluralize:"y,ies" }}.
```